# SQL select statement that would result in an associative table

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

The company I work for uses an AS400 (iSeries). There is some data in a system dictionary that I am trying to pluck out and turn into an associative table. 
Here is what the data looks like

```
xtype | xdata    
 60   | 011111211            212  
 60   |                      345   
 60   | 212312               169
```

`xtype` is the "key" that will allow me to return the relevant data.

`212,345,169` are employee numbers and are in the left 3 characters of the 24 character `xdata` column.

`011111211` is 3 "territories" (`011`, `111` and `211`), likewise `212312` is 2 "territories" (`212`, `312`)

What I would like to end up with is

```
empNum | territory    
------------------
   212 | 011      
   212 | 111      
   212 | 211        
   169 | 212    
   169 | 312
```

Here is what I have worked on so far:

```
 SELECT 
  *
 From
 (
   select 
   right(xdata,3) as empNum,
   trim(coalesce(left(xdata,3),'')) as ter
   from Table
   where xtype=60 and xarg < 960
 ) as outerTable
 where ter <> ''
```

and

```
 trim(coalesce(substr(xdata,4,3),'')) as ter
 where ter <> ''
```

would work for the second territory

and

```
 trim(coalesce(substr(xdata,7,3),'')) as ter
 where ter <> ''
```

would work for the third territory

What I don't know is how to take those 3 and join them into a result that looks like an associative table. Any thoughts?

Comment: Tasks like this aren't ideally suited to being performed within the RDBMS itself: they're often best done with an ETL tool.

Comment: Please don't format tables with non-breaking spaces. Just treat tables like code. Format them cleanly without html markup, highlight, and click on `{}`.

Comment: No, don't treat tables like code, put them in `<pre>` tags so that syntax highlighting doesn't kick in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've got one query that returns `212 | 011` / `169 | 212`, another that returns `212 | 111` / `169 | 312`, and a third that returns `212 | 211`, is that correct?

The obvious answer to transform this to the results you're asking for is to use `UNION ALL` to combine the three queries. You were looking at ways to join the queries, but (simply put) joining would add columns, when what you want to add is rows.

Comment: Yes, the assumption you have made in your first sentence is correct. I will try UNION ALL now. Thank you